# Tengo un problema que nunca habia tenido con NPM y NODE:

Tags: npm

buenas a tod@s, me acaba de surgir un issue o problema intentando actualizar un repositorio local con `npx npm-check -u`, siempre lo hago así desde un tiempo a esta parte.

Hasta ahí todo correcto, pero al ir a actualizar con `nvm y npm i -g` a la version 8.9 y pico me da problemas.

Creo que debe ser algo de rutas o symlinks

Adjunto imagenes

[image: Error consola update NPM]
[image: NVM Local Installation]

Comment: El código, incluyendo los mensajes de error, debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Por favor haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Suena a una mala relación entre tu versión de OSX y el nvm que tienes instalado (o lo que está compilado en caché de OSX, que es por lo que se queja dlyd). Sin saber mucho de OSX, tal vez reinstalando nvm (y borrando caché entre desinstalada e instalada) mejore la cosa

Comment: dyld es un gestor de enlaces dinámicos de OSX. Por eso ni siquiera npm -v funciona; algo _de fondo_ no funciona entre lo que acabas de instalar y lo que había. Sugiero que inlcuyas tu versión de OSX en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En teoria no es problema de `nvm` porque me ha funcionado todo correcto hasta el día de hoy, ayer cuando instale `npm i npm@latest -g` fue cuando empezó a fallarme, aunque si es vdd que ejecuté un `nvm cache clear` que pudo haber influido, además te lo dice el mensaje de error, creo que es un problema de Sistema Operativo, versión de `npm instalada`

Comment: SO no funciona como foro y estás usando el campo Tu Respuesta para poner un comentario. Si necesitas añadir aclaraciones, edita la pregunta todo lo que necesites. Luego, puedes borrar esta no-respuesta, por favor